# mocking from_omniauth method for testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, omniauth, rspec-rails

I would like to test the else branch. I have written "TEST THIS BRANCH" below. To hit that branch the @user.persisted? should be false. The from_omniauth is defined in User model.

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController


  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted? 

      flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: 'Facebook'
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication

    else
      //TEST THIS BRANCH
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_session_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end


end
```

The User model is defined as follows:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)

    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email ? auth.info.email : Devise.friendly_token[0,20] + "@" + Devise.friendly_token[0,20] + ".com"
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end

  end
end
```

I am doing feature testing using rspec and capybara. How can i mock self.from_omniauth(auth) so that i can test the else branch? I appreciate any insights as to how to do this correctly. Thanks!

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626850/4160532) helps.

Answer (score 0):

When doing feature tests you shouldn't be mocking any of your own code since it defeats the whole point of the end-to-end feature tests. What you can do is enable the omniauth test mode - https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing - and use that to provide any OAuth response you want that will in turn cause your code to return whatever meets the need of the branch. In your current case I'm guessing that would be a response with the same email address as an existing user, but different provider/uid (assuming your email column is required to be unique)